# TimeZone ID not found on Azure DevOps agent based on Linux

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've tried to use `TimeZoneConverter` library and codes like below to identify the proper TimeZone ID, however when running `dotnet test` on a Linux based agent, it always return the Windows compatible ID.

How can I run my tests in a Linux machine and run the project in a Windows machine without getting this exception `System.TimeZoneNotFoundException : The time zone ID 'E. South America Standard Time' was not found on the local computer.`?

```
public static TimeZoneInfo GetOSSpecificTimeZone() 
{
    return TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().Any(x => x.Id == "E. South America Standard Time") ? 
        TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. South America Standard Time") : 
        TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("America/Sao_Paulo");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get it. Why a similar ID? The IDs are correct for each platform, being the first one available on Windows and the second one available only on Linux. The problem is that GetSystemTimeZones() is returning the first one as it was available, but it's not.

Comment: It works at https://dotnetfiddle.net/UWft7T whether I use NET 4.7 (Windows) or .NET 5 (Linux). Do you have a way to reproduce this problem?

Comment: Your best bet is likely to make a `FindSystemTimeZoneById` call with your first value. If it throws an exception, try the second value. This would thus negate the need for the `GetSystemTimeZones` call.